# How do I add a Tool Tip generated from the Table Header to my JTable cells?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tooltip, jtableheader

I have a JTable and I am trying to add a header tool tip that will display the string that is in the table header for each of the header cells. I can set the value of the header cell:

`colModel.getColumn(currentColumn).setHeaderValue(time + "(s)");`

where colModel:

```
TableColumnModel colModel = audioTable.getColumnModel();
```

[image]
[image]

To do this, I've added this listener:

```
audioTable = new JTable(modelAudio);
    JTableHeader header = audioTable.getTableHeader();
    header.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("mouseMoved");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("mouseDragged");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

And I see `mouseMoved` being printed over and over again in between this NPE:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTableHeaderUI$HeaderRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.JTableHeader.getToolTipText(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.ToolTipManager$insideTimerAction.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm not sure how to get a longer stack trace, this is how I created the table:

```
modelAudio = new DefaultTableModel();
modelAudio.addColumn(" ");
audioTable = new JTable(modelAudio);
```

The tricky thing i am trying to do is to add column's dynamically, so i add a column each time the user populates the current column like so:

```
TableColumn tc = new TableColumn(modelAudio.getColumnCount());
tc.setHeaderValue(" ");
audioTable.addColumn(tc);
modelAudio.addColumn(tc);
```

Is the way that I am adding the columns the problem causing this NPE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you haven't included enough code for me to figure out why the `NullPointerException`, but fortunately that's okay because you're approaching the problem the wrong way.

You don't need to use a `MouseMotionListener` at all. Swing already supports a `ToolTip` behavior, all you need to do is get access to the cell renderer itself. Simply set the renderer to a value that will set the `ToolTipText` property before rendering the component.

You haven't included enough code for me to show you how to do this in your app, but I can show you how to do it in the [tutorial app from Oracle:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) In the initial setup, do this:

```
final TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class);
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TableCellRenderer() {
  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
      Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
      int column) {
    Component component = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    String columnHeader = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getHeaderValue().toString();
    ((JComponent) component).setToolTipText(columnHeader);
    return component;
  }
});
```

Here's the complete code of the demo with some of the unneeded code stripped out:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel {

  public SimpleTableDemo() {
    super(new GridLayout(1, 0));

    String[] columnNames = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years",
        "Vegetarian" };

    Object[][] data = {
        { "Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false) },
        { "John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true) },
        { "Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false) },
        { "Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true) },
        { "Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false) } };

    final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    final TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class);
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TableCellRenderer() {
      @Override
      public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
          Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
          int column) {
        Component component = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
            value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        String columnHeader = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column)
            .getHeaderValue().toString();
        ((JComponent) component).setToolTipText(columnHeader);
        return component;
      }
    });

    // Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    // Add the scroll pane to this panel.
    add(scrollPane);
  }

  private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    // Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Create and set up the content pane.
    SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); // content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    // Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    // creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And a screenshot (obviously my mouse isn't captured in the screenshot):

[image]

---

You can do something similar for the `ColumnHeader`, by using `table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer()`:

```
final TableCellRenderer header = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
table.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {
  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
      Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
      int column) {
    Component tableCellRendererComponent = header.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    String columnHeader = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column)
        .getHeaderValue().toString();
    ((JComponent) tableCellRendererComponent).setToolTipText(columnHeader);
    return tableCellRendererComponent;
  }
});
```

Comment: @georges Will the users not be able to double click the border of a header cell to auto-resize the column to fit the largest cell name? Or just click and drag?

Comment: @durron597 was able to see the tool tip for the header, when i add it to my code though i still get the NPE. Is this not the right way to add a column maybe?
 TableColumn tc = new TableColumn(modelAudio.getColumnCount());
tc.setHeaderValue(" ");
audioTable.addColumn(tc);
modelAudio.addColumn(tc);

Comment: @georges You haven't posted enough code to be able to debug the `NPE`. That particular bit of code probably wouldn't cause it. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32485629/edit) your question with additional information.

Comment: @durron597 in an effort to duplicate the problem with a subset of the code i thought relevant i cannot duplicate the NPE. Thank you for all your help, the header tool tip works on my subset i will just keep re-adding till i find the issue. Thanks again - I owe you a beer.